# Use the css class or variable in Typescript file in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

Is there a way to use the scss `class` or `variable` in the typescript file?

`scss`

```
.thisIsGreen {
   color: green;
}
.thisIsBlue {
   color: blue;
}
```

or

```
$thisIsGreen {
  color: green;
}
$thisIsBlue {
  color: blue;
}
```

Now in the typescript I would like to use this `class` or `variable`.

`component.ts`

```
const colors = ['thisIsGreen', 'thisIsBlue'];
```

I would like to use the colors in my charts, so don't know how can I use the css variable or class, instead of hardcoding the color in component.ts.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you assign colors to the chart?

Comment: @ShreenilPatel I can make it work with charts colors if I hard code the colors array i.e. `colors = ['#ccc', '#ddd']` . Only the thing is, now I wanted to use my class or global variable in scss to make it work with the charts in .ts file. Thanks

Comment: what library are you using for the charts?

Comment: @yannick ngx-echarts

Answer (score -1):

I had used in my project the following: (Use of stylesheet(css) in TypeScript(.ts) file in Angular)

```
let greet1:HTMLElement = document.getElementById("greet1");
greet1.innerHTML = '<i class="pi pi-caret-down" style="vertical-align:bottom;float:inherit;display: inline-block;">  </i>' +' ' + event.item.label + ' ';
```

In InnerHTML you can have different HTML attributes like style, float, display etc: [Css at .ts in Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB5Z3.png).

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.